# Designing a Turing Machine for $f(n) = 4⌊(1/4)n⌋ +1$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, turing-machines

[Design a Turing Machine to construct the function f(n) = 4⌊(1/4)n⌋ + 1, (that is, 1 more than 4× the integer part of (1/4)n) for n ∈ N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbZ9C.jpg)

Am I wrong in assuming that the machine in the end will just add 1 to the original? If I am (which is very likely):

Am I wrong in assuming that I can just construct the desired TM by just adding the required functions? I.e. TM that quarters n. Then add TM that multiplies by 4. Then add TM that adds 1.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You forgot the floor symbol in the title (Just saying)

Comment: $4\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor\neq n$. Try with a few values of $n$ and see. Also, the simplest TM for this function is a lot simpler than composing the TM's for each of the component functions, at least if the input is binary.

Comment: @Arthur Ah, right, of course. Thats obvious now. In that case, how would i go about constructing a TM for this?

Comment: Write $n$ in binary and see what happens to it in the end.